# PHP require ONLY specific function from file

Tags: php, require, function-calls

Can i require/include/import a specific function declared in another .php file, without require/include/import the entire file, like in Java? For example something like this:

file1

```
function test(){echo "OK";}

function test2(){echo "Not OK";}
```

file2

```
require "file1.php test"
test();
```

Comment: No, if you want to separate functions, put them in classes?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I guess you need this because probably there are some other code in `file1.php` that will execute if you include `file1.php` and you don't want this. Am I correct?

Comment: @Nima yes, thats exactly the point.

Comment: So move the function you need into its own file, and require *that* file from everywhere that needs it

Comment: I don't know why people down vote so quick... This is a valid question.

Comment: @ndelucca It would be a good practice if you put definitions and executable code in different files. For example, create a new file `function_definitions.php` and add function definitions to that file, and in `file1.php` include this new file and use those functions. Putting definitions and the rest of the code in same file is what causes this problem.

Comment: @Nima i understand, but this is not entirely my code, and i cannot modify things as i please, so i was looking for a solution that didn't require asking permission from someone else

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, even with Java the whole file is included you just don't see what's going on behind the scenes.

Simple answer, add your function to it's own file, also known as OOP.

Comment: what i ment with Java is that you can import individual class methods without importing the entire class.

Comment: Adding function to it's own file is __not__ OOP btw.

Comment: No but creating a class for the object holding all of it's methods is.